Sequelize Included model's where clause is ignored
I have a issue where i'm passing in a where clause into a included associated model and the where clause is ignored. Below is smaller sample of what i have since i can't post the actual columns and data, but the generated sql looks to have everything except the where clause for the TableC is missing. Pretty sure the associations are working fine since i have other queries and other code where they work perfectly together, it's simply just this one condition not working... Table C has a FK with Table A (e.g. table c has a column tableAId with a fk with the id for that table)
await TableA.findAll({
  where: {
    id: 1
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: TableB 
    },
    {
      model: TableC,
      where: {
        foo: 'bar'
      }
    }
  ],
});


Could you add the generated SQL to the post?

   await TableA.findAll({
  where: {
    id: 1
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: TableB 
    },
    {
      model: TableC,
      where: {
        foo: 'bar'
      },
      required: true
    }
  ],
});

add that required flag in when using condition in association.
